# How do I get the SQL code to display properly?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to have a "case level suggested" field update with the letters A,B,C,or D based on the value. However, the code works but only displays "B" for everything over 3. How do I fix this?

**Here is the code:**

```
SELECT [Calculated Total].casemain_id, [Calculated Total].category, Sum([Calculated Total].Total) AS SumOfTotal, IIf([SumOfTotal]>=4,"B",IIf([SumOfTotal]<=3,"A",IIf([SumOfTotal]>=6,"C",IIf([SumOfTotal]>=9,"D","C")))) AS [Case Level Suggested]
FROM [Calculated Total]
GROUP BY [Calculated Total].casemain_id, [Calculated Total].category;
```

Comment: What database are you using?  Typically, literal values are wrapped with single quotes unless you are executing dynamic SQL.  If you are using SQL Server, take a look at https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_iif.asp (uses single quote, not double).

Comment: I am using Microsoft Access

Comment: Add the MSAccess tag, that way you will get the MS Access crowd looking at your question also.  Then double quotes are valid in Access :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is the way that `IIf` works, from left to right according to the order that they are written in your code:

- Is the total less than or equal to 3? - If so, then "A";
- Is the total greater than or equal to 4? - If so then "B"

Assuming that these are integer totals, then these two checks cover all numbers, and the rest of the checks are not made. Instead, try:

```
SELECT [Calculated Total].casemain_id, [Calculated Total].category, Sum([Calculated Total].Total) AS SumOfTotal, 
IIf([SumOfTotal]<=3,"A",IIf([SumOfTotal]>=9,"D",IIf([SumOfTotal]>=6,"C",IIf([SumOfTotal]>=4,"B","C")))) AS [Case Level Suggested]
FROM [Calculated Total]
GROUP BY [Calculated Total].casemain_id, [Calculated Total].category;
```

Regards,

Comment: Great, that works! Would you be able to answer if I wanted to apply this to the 'Category' to apply this code to only 'trays' and different parameters for 'equip'

Comment: Please post a new question, explaining exactly what you are after, and what you have.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, `IIF` evaluates to the first `True` condition met. Hence as soon as `B` is assigned, it does not re-adjust for overlapping conditions. Ideally, consider mutually exclusive conditions:

```
IIf([SumOfTotal <= 3,'A',
   IIF([SumOfTotal] >= 4 AND [SumOfTotal] < 6, 'B',   
        IIf([SumOfTotal] >= 6 AND [SumOfTotal] < 9, 'C',
           IIf([SumOfTotal] >= 9, 'D','C')))) AS [Case Level Suggested]
```

Alternatively, use `SWITCH`:

```
SWITCH([SumOfTotal] <=3,'A',
       [SumOfTotal] >=4 AND [SumOfTotal] < 6, 'B',
       [SumOfTotal] >=6 AND [SumOfTotal] < 9, 'C',
       [SumOfTotal] >=9, 'D',
       True, 'C') AS [Case Level Suggested]
```